# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface

Tags: api, magento2.2, interface

I have a preference in di.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <preference for="Magento\CatalogRule\Api\Data\RuleInterface" type="Module\Vendor\Model\RuleInterface" />
    </config>
```

I want add methods to an interface, but when I access to interface with postman, Magento have the error PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface.

Why?

Thanks!

Comment: please clear the **var** folder and then running `setup:upgrade`. If this doesn't solve it then look for errors in di.xml files

Comment: I run the commands but not work, and execute setup:di:compile but nothing

Comment: I think you're not supposed to put a interface class in Model when building apis